# Socket connection between rails and iphone native app

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, sockets, websocket, chat

I have an iphone app with rails serving as a backend server.

Now I need to implement a chat functionality using sockets connections.

A lot of examples show you how to implement chat using sockets in browser.

What I need here is how I can implement an application where you create socket server in the rails app , and the client in iphone app which listens to the channel I give them.

I tried using faye(examples given only how to implement client in the browser) and using fayeObjC library for iphone to create client, but am not able to listen to the channel from this library.I know I must be implementing it wrong here.

I'll share my code also here, but first I need to know is there a better solution than this?

Also I appreciate some links to some examples where socket server is in rails and clients are iphone app.

**Appreciate any help and mostly need a right direction to implement it.**

---

**Update**

I tried the faye combination again and it worked.Although still looking for more solutions.

Comment: maybe will help you a bit... http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server and http://boddhisattvadedicates.blogspot.in/2011/08/chat-application-using-ruby.html or http://quickblox.com/modules/chat/

Comment: hey thank you so much for these links. helped a lot clear of some concepts. although I tried the faye combination again and it worked.Although would love to try more options.

Comment: So.. :) If this was helpful.. can I put my comment .. like an answer.. and could you please accept it? :)

Comment: Tony sorry for such a late reply.But sure add it as a answer and I'll accept it.Btw I liked this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server, this is exactly what I want to achieve but any idea how to do it with ruby.

Comment: And also creating sockets through ruby, would be slow and unsecured.So any help if you can provide on making it secure and scalable is also much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help you :) +1 for your question

Comment: @Anidhya Ahuja: I am trying for the same kind and i still could not find things so helpful. I saw your update saying faye combination working, so could you please share how you have made it to work. Also i would like to know where you have hosted because i tried in openshift and heroku. In openshift it is working but getting disconnected often whereas in heroku it doesn't even work. please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check about **TCP sockets**:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server
- [Chat Application Using Ruby](http://boddhisattvadedicates.blogspot.in/2011/08/chat-application-using-ruby.html)
- http://quickblox.com/modules/chat/
- http://caydenliew.com/2011/11/ios-mac-os-communication-with-asyncsocket/
- http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxix-message

Next link is a comprehensive Networking Guide - [Using Internet Sockets](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html)

You must keep in mind two major problems to peer-to-peer communications (Chat): reachability and how to receive new messages while your application is in the background (get notifications).
For the last you can use **APNS approach**: an invisible notification will be pushed to the iPhone indicating that a new message is ready to be read. So your app will make a request for unread messages (what app like WhatsApp does).

Besides TCP sockets you could use **websockets** (HTTP - so there are no firewall problems).
Best in class - [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/#home).
Here you will find the wiki https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki (you will find there an extension for Ruby also)

Here an example for [iOS chat client for socket.io & node.js backend](https://github.com/honcheng/iOS-nodechat)

**Jabber**

Another option: **XMPP** - "stands for eXtensible Messaging and Presence Protocol. Such a protocol is open-standard and oriented to message exchange (builds and maintains by Jabber community). Message exchange happens near real time, so it is an ideal infrastructure to build chat-like applications. The protocol also implements a mechanism to notify presence information (whether a user is online or not) and the maintenance of a contact list. XMPP is a thorough protocol, which has been adopted also by big companies like Google to build their Instant Messaging service."

Here you will find all about developing a Jabber Client for iOS (enable users to sign in, add buddies, and send messages; how to install and configure a jabber server, create accounts, and interact with the server from an iOS application http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/

Answer (score 0):

I know that [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) by square is a strong native Objective-C library. But it doesn't offer the channel abstraction you seem to be looking for.

If you would consider outsourcing the WebSocket connections then you could use a hosted service like [Pusher](http://pusher.com), who I work for. You can publish messages (trigger events) on channels using the [pusher-gem](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem). And you can subscribe to channels and receive messages using one of [Pusher's Objective-C libraries](http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries#objective-c).

Other solutions will also have Objective-C libraries and you can find a list of them via this [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide).

Comment: Am actually not looking for outsourcing the Websocket connection, only that I want implement my own , so I can have my custom methods to have a custom rule to retrieve messages. But thanks for the help.